# Ошибка миграции EF GetDbProviderManifestToken MySql, как победить?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

Делаю в консоли NuGet  `PM>Enable-Migrations -Force`

Ловлю текст  Checking if the context targets an existing database...
 а за тем исключение

> System.NullReferenceException: Ссылка на объект не указывает на
>   экземпляр объекта.    в
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection)    в
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection)    в
>   MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlManifestTokenResolver.ResolveManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection)    в
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection
>   connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest)    в
>   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection
>   providerConnection)    в
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext
>   internalContext)    в
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy 2.GetValue(TInput input)    в
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>   в
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ModelBeingInitialized()
>   в System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(DbContext
>   context, XmlWriter writer)    в
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(XmlWriter
>   w)    в
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(Action`1
>   writeXml)    в
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(DbContext
>   context)    в
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration
>   configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState
>   existenceState, Boolean calledByCreateDatabase)    в
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration
>   configuration)    в
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration
>   migrationsConfiguration)    в
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Run()
>   в System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>   в System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner
>   runner)    в
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldInitialCreate(String
>   language, String rootNamespace)    в
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action
>   command) Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

Пробовал удалять папку Migrations - не помагает. 
Старые миграции есть, но NuGet консоль их почему-то не видит. Скорее всего прибился migration, он куда-то сохраняет данные о проэкте.

Версии
База MySql

EF v 6.0

VS 2017

Как оживить Migrations? Или это проблема самого EF-MySql библиотеки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начнём с Configuration.cs

```
internal sealed class Configuration :   
DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyProj.Domain.Concrete.MysqlEfDbContext> { ...}
```

Здесь переходим на сам Context

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class MysqlEfDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MysqlEfDbContext() : this("MysqlEfDbContext"/*Строка подключения*/){ }
```

Особенность, пакет хочет что б для MySql в строка подключения была строка подключения, на en so есть предложение поменять на   `this("server=127.0.0.1;Database=sys;uid=root;pwd=root;Allow User Variables=True")`
Но тогда получаем другую интересную "особенность". Код перестаёт нормально функционировать (появляются странные Exceptions), а консоль работает нормально. Что бы выйти из положения, можно написать функцию, которая для web-приложения вернёт алиас, а для консоли - строку подключения. Получилось так:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class MysqlEfDbContext : DbContext
{    
    public MysqlEfDbContext() :  this(getDBConnectionString("MysqlEfDbContext")) { }
    static string  getDBConnectionString(string connName) {            
        string loc = typeof(MysqlEfDbContext).Assembly.Location;
        string file = getConfigLoc(loc);
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(file)) {            
            file = loc.Substring(0, loc.LastIndexOf('\\')) + "\\__AssemblyInfo__.ini";                
            using (System.IO.StreamReader rd = new System.IO.StreamReader(file, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode)) file = rd.ReadToEnd();
            if (!(file = file.Split('\0')[1].Replace("file:///", "")).Contains("inetpub")) file = getConfigLoc(file);
            else return connName; // Случай когда Web публикация
        }               
        System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();            
        doc.Load( file);
        System.Xml.XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("/configuration/connectionStrings/add[@name='{0}']/@connectionString", connName));            
        return (node == null) ? "" : node.InnerText;           
       }

    static string getConfigLoc(string location) {
        List<string> dirs = new List<string>(location.Split("\\/".ToCharArray()));
        return string.Join("\\", dirs.GetRange(0, dirs.Count - 4).ToArray()) 
    + "\\MyProj.WebUI\\web.config"; // Добавить папку Web-Приложения
    }
```

Откатал и в работе, и три команды NuGet консоли (или Pkgmgr.exe):
    Enable-Migrations     Add-Migration "Название",     Update-Database 
Работают.

P.S. Ещё у меня возник странный Еxception при Update-Database

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Не разрешен тип
>   члена "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException,MySql.Data,
>   Version=7.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d".
>   в System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner
>   runner)    в
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String
>   targetMigration, Boolean force)    в
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action
>   command) Не разрешен тип члена
>   "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException,MySql.Data, Version=7.0.2.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d".

В этом случае, рекомендую использовать `Update-Database -Verbose`,
тогда понятно, что последняя sql-команда вызвала исключение, тогда нужно смотреть на базу данных - исправить ошибку меняя код процедур `Up` (реже `Down()` в миграциях (папка Migrations).