# EF Core не работают миграции - ошибку не выдает

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

Создаю приложение использую многоуровневый подход - поначалу миграции работают, потом перестают - никак не могу понять причину. В консоли просто думает немного и потом без какого- либо текста опять возвращает консоль. Использую mySQL от Pomelo. но не думаю что в этом может быть проблема, так как даже создавать миграцию не хочет, не работает все - от создания до применения - результат одинаковый.

Comment: Сделал несколько испытаний - миграции не работают в библиотеке классов. Непонятный момент, неужели для миграций нужна точка входа так.

Comment: Для миграции - проэкт должен быть собран, без ошибок сборки. Проэкт подшивается к мигратору. Дальше, предположительно сериализацией, считается хеш-сумма "структуры" СУБД, если по хешу структура совпала - миграция не делается. Если не совпала - хеш должен совпасть с хешом одного из шагов миграции. А вот если таблица миграций повреждена (или хеш в ней не найден) тогда скорее всего миграция не возможна.

Comment: У меня с МуSql проблемы были, возможно поможет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/736313/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-ef-getdbprovidermanifesttoken-mysql-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c

Comment: Ну это понятно, что при любой миграции проект компилируется, дело в том, что ничего не происходит просто, я пробовал и с другими провайдерами - от них не зависит. Выявил зависимость лишь от типа проекта - просто не работает в библиотеке классов, может еще где, все не проверял.

Comment: У вас хеш найден? Он совпадает с миграциями?

Comment: Какой кэш, я не совсем понимаю? Там самая простая команда add-migration ничего не делает, а ей надо лишь контекст и модели насколько я знаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причины такого поведения я так и не понял. Есть вариант либо не делать библиотеку классов, а использовать консольку,либо редактировать файл проекта библиотеки классов.
Мне второй вариант больше нравится(хотя в любом случае это глупости) - надо просто добавить строку-

```
<GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
```